# Cython parallel is confusing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, openmp, cython

I have been trying all online examples to understand Cython parallel using OpenMP. After running and in comparison to the non-parallel code, it is not improving performance (maybe worse). Maybe I need to install extra libraries other than Cython, or software on Windows (I am not sure). Below is a simple example that I run, but it doesn't work:

```
from cython.parallel cimport prange
from cython import boundscheck, wraparound

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def serial(double[:, :] a):
    cdef:
        double total = 0
        int i, j
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            total += a[i, j]
    return total

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def parallel(double[:, :] a):
    cdef:
        double total = 0
        int i, j
    for i in prange(a.shape[0],
                    nogil=True, 
                    schedule='static'):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            total += a[i, j]
    return total
```

For running:

```
import par1
import numpy as np

r, c = 100, 100
a    = np.random.randn(r, c)   # this takes ~6.75 sec

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    %timeit par1.serial(a)
    %timeit par1.parallel(a)
```

Results:

```
11.6 µs ± 189 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
11.7 µs ± 200 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The parallel try is actually slower! Do I need to install some extra libraries other than Cython or possibly corresponding to Windows? Or there is something wrong in the code?

I tried another example as below:

```
from cython.parallel cimport parallel, prange
from libc.stdlib cimport abort, malloc, free
cimport openmp

cdef int sq(int x) nogil:
    return x*x

cdef int tri(int x) nogil:
    return x*x*x

def testpar(int n):
    cdef int i, numthreads, total
    cdef int * squared
    cdef int * tripled
    cdef size_t size = 10

    with nogil, parallel(num_threads=2):
        numthreads = openmp.omp_get_num_threads()
        print(numthreads)

        squared = <int *> malloc(size(n) * n)
        tripled = <int *> malloc(size(n) * n)

        for i in prange(n, schedule='dynamic'):
            squared[i] = sq(i)
            tripled[i] = tri(i) + sq(i)

        free(squared)
        free(tripled)
```

When I setup it it gives me this error:

```
 Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
par3.c
par3.c(1): fatal error C1189: #error:  Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

Can Anyone help to understand how paralleization is done in Cython ?

Comment: `size(n)` is your "gil-requiring function" (because it doesn't exist, so Cython assumes it must be a Python function). You probably meant `sizeof`

Comment: I tried your suggestions it yields: `Converting to Python object not allowed without gil`

Comment: The problem is in this `numthreads = openmp.omp_get_num_threads()`. I think the declaration `cdef int numthreads` is not proper

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `numthreads = openmp.omp_get_num_threads()`. However, `print(numthreads)` does need the GIL

Comment: yes, `print` is the problem. Thanks

Comment: Regarding your initial example, `parallel()` was faster than `serial()` for me after a few modifications. In both functions I changed the arguments to `(double[:, ::1] a):` and then I created auxiliary shape integers. `cdef long shape0=a.shape[0], shape1=a.shape[1]`. I think the main issue might be calling `a.shape[1]` in the inner loop. This might disable the possibility for some compiler loop optimizations. Though for a better comparison, you should release the GIL for the serial function too with e.g. `with nogil:`